# How do I facet a ggplot2 based graph from qicharts2 package?

Tags: r, ggplot2

*qicharts2* is a statistical process control package that plots control charts. Let us plot an example chart:

```
library(qicharts2)
library(ggplot2)

(plot1 <- qic(age,
  data    = tail(cabg, 100), 
  chart   = 'i',
  exclude = c(45, 70),
  title   = 'Age of the last 100 patients (I chart)',
  ylab    = 'Years',
  xlab    = 'Patient #')
  )
p1 <- plot1$data
```

I can customize this chart pulling the data from it `plot1$data` and doing typical ggplot2 customization. See below.

```
(plot2 <- ggplot(plot1$data, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_ribbon(ymin = p1$lcl, ymax = p1$ucl, fill = "green", alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_line(colour = "blue", size = .75) + 
  geom_line(aes(x, cl)) +
  geom_point(colour = "black" , fill = "black", size = 1.5) +
  ggtitle(label = "example i chart") +
  labs(x = NULL,
       y = NULL)+
  theme_minimal()
  )
```

Let us go ahead and facet plot 1 by gender, and we'll call it plot 3.

```
(plot3 <- qic(age,
  data    = tail(cabg, 100), 
  chart   = 'i',
  exclude = c(45, 70),
  title   = 'Age of the last 100 patients (I chart)',
  ylab    = 'Years',
  xlab    = 'Patient #', 
  facet   = ~ gender)
)
p3 <- plot3$data
```

I want to create a `plot 4` that uses the same options as `plot 2` but is faceted like `plot 3`. What do I need to add to my second chunk of code to make it faceted by gender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `facet` you're looking for is stored in `plot3$data$facet1` column

```r
library(qicharts2)
library(ggplot2)

plot3 <- qic(age,
             data    = tail(cabg, 100),
             chart   = 'i',
             exclude = c(45, 70),
             title   = 'Age of the last 100 patients (I chart)',
             ylab    = 'Years',
             xlab    = 'Patient #',
             facet   = ~ gender)

p3 <- plot3$data

plot4 <- ggplot(p3, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_ribbon(ymin = lcl, ymax = ucl, fill = "green", alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_line(colour = "blue", size = .75) + 
  geom_line(aes(x, cl)) +
  geom_point(colour = "black" , fill = "black", size = 1.5) +
  ggtitle(label = "example i chart") +
  labs(x = NULL,
       y = NULL)+
  theme_minimal() +
  facet_grid(~ facet1)
plot4
```

[image]

Created on 2018-03-23 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: How'd you figure that out? Where do I look to find where things are stored?

Comment: Run `str(plot3$data)` to see the structure of the data

Comment: I found changing `facet_grid(~ p3$facet1)` to `facet_grid(~ facet1)` leads to better results when adding additional lines/points on top of this graph.

Comment: You are right. I don't know why I wrote that code that way. You're not supposed to refer to a column of a data frame within `ggplot2` like that. Thanks for the follow up!